# Merge multiple values for same key to one dict/json (Pandas, Python, Dataframe)?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2], 'key': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'value': ['kkk', 'aaa', '5', 'kkk','8']})
```

I want to convert it to the following data frame:

```
id  value
1   {'a':['kkk', 'aaa'], 'b': 5}
2   {'a':['kkk'], 'b': 8}
```

I am trying to do this using `.to_dict` method but the output is

```
df.groupby(['id','key']).aggregate(list).groupby('id').aggregate(list)
```

> {'value': {1: [['kkk', 'aaa'], ['5']], 2: [['kkk'], ['8']]}}

Should I perform dict comprehension or there is an efficient logic to build such generic json/dict?

Comment: Is it okay if the values for keys are always stored as lists for e.g. in such case the value for `b` would be `[5]` instead of `5`?

Comment: Yes, no problem. It simplifies the solution? @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `groupby(['id', 'key'])` and `agg(list)`, you can group by the first level of the index and for each group thereof, use `droplevel` + `to_dict`:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['id', 'key']).agg(list).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['value'].droplevel(0).to_dict()).reset_index(name='value')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   id                              value
0   1  {'a': ['kkk', 'aaa'], 'b': ['5']}
1   2         {'a': ['kkk'], 'b': ['8']}
```

Or, simpler:

```
new_df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.groupby('key')['value'].agg(list).to_dict())
```

Comment: Seems to be non trivial at all @richardec

Comment: Do you mean it seems to be *not* trivial?

Comment: Yep, can you please explain the last part:
groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.droplevel(0).to_dict()).reset_index(name='value')

Comment: @SteveS I just added a shorter solution I discovered. :)

Comment: @richardec Good answer. I liked the 2nd solution.

Comment: Bravissimo richardec!!!!
The second one is simply genius!

Comment: So @richardec the second solution take a group as x and aggregates using the keys?

Comment: Yes. For each unique `id`, it groups again by `key` then does `agg(list)` and converts the result to a dict.

Comment: And the ['value'] part is because we need the values per id, per key and then aggregate them into list using the agg(list)? @richardec

Comment: Yep! If you remove `['value']`, each resulting dict will be wrapped in a object like this: `{"value":...}` instead of just `...`